# How to eliminate the delay in the while loop command?

Tags: scripting

I have tried:

```
$ while true; do echo "runfast"; sleep 1 ; done
```

However, I need to wait 1 second to another "echo runfast". Then, I want to accelerate as much I can without a sleep, like non stopping. Can you help me?

Sorry if it is a noob question to this forum.

Comment: "Accelerate"? If you want it to run repeatedly without pausing, remove the `sleep` part. Scripting is such a broad term here. Is this bash you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the sleep:

```
while true; do echo "runfast" ; done
```